# Double Upload When Releasing With mule-domain-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, mule, maven-plugin, nexus

I am attempting to release a Mule domain using the mule-domain-maven-plugin. I've noticed when invoking install, that the main *.zip artifact is installed, followed by the *.pom, followed by a second copy of the *.zip:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ esb-common ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/chase/git/dn2k/dn2k-esb/esb-common/target/esb-common-2.6.7.0.zip to /Users/chase/.m2/repository/com/dn2k/esb-common/2.6.7.0/esb-common-2.6.7.0.zip
[INFO] Installing /Users/chase/git/dn2k/dn2k-esb/esb-common/pom.xml to /Users/chase/.m2/repository/com/dn2k/esb-common/2.6.7.0/esb-common-2.6.7.0.pom
[INFO] Installing /Users/chase/git/dn2k/dn2k-esb/esb-common/target/esb-common-2.6.7.0.zip to /Users/chase/.m2/repository/com/dn2k/esb-common/2.6.7.0/esb-common-2.6.7.0.zip
```

A bit odd, perhaps, but harmless.

However, when attempting to release, a similar sequence is followed. First the main *.zip artifact is uploaded to Nexus, then the *.pom, then  maven-metadata.xml, then finally a second copy of the main *.zip artifact:

```
[INFO] Uploading: http://<hostname>/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/dn2k/esb-common/2.6.7.0/esb-common-2.6.7.0.zip
[INFO] Uploaded: http://<hostname>/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/dn2k/esb-common/2.6.7.0/esb-common-2.6.7.0.zip (2 KB at 7.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://<hostname>/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/dn2k/esb-common/2.6.7.0/esb-common-2.6.7.0.pom
[INFO] Uploaded: http://<hostname>/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/dn2k/esb-common/2.6.7.0/esb-common-2.6.7.0.pom (2 KB at 6.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://<hostname>/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/dn2k/esb-common/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.dn2k:esb-common/maven-metadata.xml in dn2k-deployment (http://<hostname>/nexus/content/repositories/releases/)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /Users/myron/.m2/repository/com/dn2k/esb-common/resolver-status.properties
[INFO] Uploading: http://<hostname>/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/dn2k/esb-common/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Uploaded: http://<hostname>/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/dn2k/esb-common/maven-metadata.xml (302 B at 1.4 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for http://<hostname>/nexus/content/repositories/releases/
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://<hostname>/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ with username=admin, password=***
[INFO] Uploading: http://<hostname>/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/dn2k/esb-common/2.6.7.0/esb-common-2.6.7.0.zip
^^^^ ERRORS OUT ^^^^
```

On this second upload, Nexus balks, as we have it configured to disallow multiple uploads of the same released artifact.

In the [source code for the plugin](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-esb-maven-tools/blob/master/plugins/mule-domain-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/mule/tools/maven/plugin/domain/MuleDomainMojo.java), line 88 identifies the zip file as the main artifact, and just one line above identifies that same file as an attachment. This double identification is what causes the maven-install-plugin to do the double copy to the ~/.m2/repository as shown above.

Is this a bug, or am I failing to configure the plugin correctly? Does anyone have an example of a successful release using the mule-domain-maven-plugin?

Here's the pom for the esb-common (domain) project (version managed to 1.1 for the plugin):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>com.dn2k</groupId>
     <artifactId>esb-common</artifactId>
     <packaging>mule-domain</packaging>

     <parent>
        <groupId>com.dn2k</groupId>
        <artifactId>esb-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7.0</version>
     </parent>

     <build>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
              <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>mule-domain-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <extensions>true</extensions>
           </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </build>

  </project>
```

Comment: This is simply a bug in the mule-domain-maven-plugin which attaches two times the same artifact....Or an other plugin execution attaches also a zip file name with the same name...

Comment: I think you're right. I'll file an issue and see if the mulesoft team has something to add that I'm not seeing. Thanks for looking.

Comment: I opened a ticket, too. If I get some updates, I post them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a case for mulesoft team. They now fixed my ticket. This was clearly a bug. Luckily I doesn't get these redudant installing message anymore, if I use the latest mule version and mule plugin.

```
[INFO] Installing C:\project\workspaces\workspace_mule\zzzz\pom.xml to C:\Users\charmin\.m2\repository\com\mycompany\zzzz\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\zzzz-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing C:\project\workspaces\workspace_mule\zzzz\target\zzzz-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip to C:\Users\charmin\.m2\repository\com\mycompany\zzzz\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\zzzz-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```